# Dont know how to implement form with my blog

Tags: php

I want the user to confirm a popup when trying to delete something from the blog. But I just don't know what to put as "action" in the form. When you click DELETE it should make a popup and ask you YES/NO, if you click NO you stay where you are, if you click yes the article gets deleted.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

del_confirmation_form.php

```
<div class="popup">
    <h1>Skutocne chces odstranit tento príspevok?</h1>
    <form action="index.php?str=blog_view&id=<?php echo $id;?>" method="post">
        <input class="ms-input ms-center ms-black" type="text" name="blog_del" value="<?php echo $row["title"];?>" disabled><p></p>
        <input type="submit" name="zmazat" value="Ano" style="cursor: pointer; margin-right:32px;">
        <input type="submit" name="zmazat" value="Nie" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </form>
</div>
```

blog_backend.php

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['delete'])){
        $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM blog_data WHERE id = '".$id."'";
        mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $sel="select id from blog_data where id = '".$id."'";
        $ress = mysqli_query($con, $sel);
        $pocet_zaznamov = mysqli_num_rows($ress);
        if ($pocet_zaznamov != 0) {
            header("Location: index.php?str=blog&error=not_deleted");
        }else{
            header("Location: index.php?str=blog&info=deleted");
        }
        mysqli_close($con);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: You don't need to amend the action..what you need is some JavaScript to intercept the form's submit event

Comment: For the confirmation you need a Javascript snippet and issue a "confirm()" call. Or you can go the full mile and add jQuery / jConfirm. Then, when you send the POST command, simply add a hidden field named "delete" - the value does not matter since you're just checking it `isset()`.

Comment: ...however, this is not the kind of question that's answered on Stack Overflow. You should check out some tutorial for forms or the like, *then* try implementing your version, *then* if it doesn't work post here what you attempted, what the results were and what you expected instead. You should also look at the FAQ and quick tour sections of Stack Overflow.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ for SQL injection attacks! Use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead of injecting user data directly into your queries like that. If you got a simple request with the data `' OR 1=1;--` as `id` and all contents in your `blog_data` table would be removed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have some functions against that.

Comment: @Vladeno - Not in the posted code. And you shouldn't have "some functions" for that. I you do, you're doing it wrong. Don't manually sanitize/escape the data. The by far safest way to protect against SQL injections are prepared statements.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to learn and use the prepared statements.